# IsChanged or IsNew

Tags: validation-rule

I had an interview recently, question was like : On update trigger a validation rule to check if entered amount is greater than zero.

I answered, we can achieve it by using ischanged formula field along with checking amount < 0 condition.

But interviewer said its not an apt solution, rather IsChanged, he said to use IsNew formula equal false + amount < 0 would be the solution.

But why not IsNew considered as a solution. Is my doubt????

Answer (score 3):

If a record was initially created with a value less than 0 and that record was updated without that field being changed, a formula with `ISCHANGED()` wouldn't catch that the value is less than 0, but a formula with `NOT(ISNEW())` would.

`ISCHANGED()` looks at a particular field to see whether that field has been changed.

`ISNEW()` looks at the entire record and whether or not the record is new.